# React Native Web for web only project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I like the cleaness of react-native where everything is a `<View/>` component and am considering using it for web only project.

There are 3 concerns which make me hesitate

1. probably there are much more web component for web environment. (so plain react might offer more library for web development)
2. not sure if RN-web has any disadvantage over React on SEO?
3. Would it be possible to mix in react.js code when needed? (just like we go out to android/ios native side when we can't do everything in RN side)

I'd like to hear from whoever tried using RN-web for web project.

- edit

The reason why I want RN-web is mostly because our RN code base is much bigger than web even though this project is web-only. (and I feel RN is much cleaner, I don't know why :()

Comment: If it is a web-only project, just go with React. You can extend it into a PWA.

Comment: We used RN-Web for a project with both web and native versions. If only interested in web... why wouldn't you use React? Everything into a <View /> seems very bad in terms of HTML semantics (everything gets converted to a div)